# Issue parsing JSON not in array format

Tags: json, swift, swift5

Essentially I would like to take the following JSON and use the data within my project.

To parse the data I need to create a structure - in the past I used this for arrays:

**Structure:**

```
struct ArrayStruct: Codable {
    let info1: String
    let info2: String
}
```

**Array:**

```
[
  {
    "info1": "Information",
    "info2": "More"
  }
]
```

**What would the structure for the following data look like?**

```
{
  "error": false,
  "response": "",
  "message": "",
  "general": {
    "customer": "Customer1",
    "code": "CO1234",
    "name": "Machine Name",
    "category": "machine"
  },
  "details": {
    "taken": "July 15th 2020",
    "created": "November 2nd 2020",
    "packed": "",
    "delivered": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely you must have tried something?

Answer (score 1):

I made a structure using struct with codeable  for the data you gave

```
struct MainResponse : Codable {
    let details : Detail?
    let error : Bool?
    let general : General?
    let message : String?
    let response : String?

    // coding keys not required for this as the data keys are same but added just as an example
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case details = "details"
        case error = "error"
        case general = "general"
        case message = "message"
        case response = "response"
    }
}

struct Detail : Codable {
    let created : String?
    let delivered : String?
    let packed : String?
    let taken : String?
}

struct General : Codable {
    let category : String?
    let code : String?
    let customer : String?
    let name : String?
}
```

Comment: Why is every property optional? Nothing should be made optional unless it actually can be set to nil.

Comment: It Might be possible to come some values nil but if you are sure that you will not get any nil values than you can go with force to unwrap

Comment: That is a bad idea compared to having a correct design from the start.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create your data Struct like this

```
struct MainResponse : Codable {
   let error : Bool?
   let response : String?
   let message : String?
   let general : General?
   let details : Details?
}
```

Make your General Struct like this

```
struct General : Codable {
   let customer : String?
   let code : String?
   let name : String?
   let category : String?
}
```

Make your Detail Struct like this

```
struct Details : Codable {
   let taken : String?
   let created : String?
   let packed : String?
   let delivered : String?
}
```

Comment: Data is a keyword. Data should be RespData or Something else

Answer (score 0):

its easy to create structures now days, there are various tools available, just input the response you will get the data structure, used the following to generate the structure

[quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io)

```
    // MARK: - Customer
struct Customer: Codable {
    let error: Bool?
    let response, message: String?
    let general: General?
    let details: Details?
}

// MARK: - Details
struct Details: Codable {
    let taken, created, packed, delivered: String?
}

// MARK: - General
struct General: Codable {
    let customer, code, name, category: String?
}
```